# Do I need JBoss Developer Studio to debug source-code running on JBoss Fuse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

Do I need to install JBoss Developer Studio from Red Hat or can I just use Eclipse to debug source-code running on JBoss Fuse? JBoss Developer Studio is based on Eclipse so it seems like this maybe an option.

My problem is that I have no experience with JBoss Developer Studio and do not want to waste precious time scaling this learning curve. Also, I like how Eclipse is totally free and does not have any licensing requirements. Red Hat stuff uses open-source tech but then has all this nasty license fee stuff like proprietary software. :/

Thanks for reading this. :D

Regards,

Comment: This is sort of a duplicate. :/ I am interested in learning how to execute my application on Fuse after having uploaded it to Fuse through my Maven repo though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer you initial question: No, you do not *need* to install JBoss Developer Studio, you can use any IDE that can debug a Java VM.

But JBoss Developer Studio definitely makes it easier to setup and debug your Fuse and JBoss runtimes.

And about learning curve then Developer Studio is built on Eclipse and provide the exact same features + generic features we find useful and specific features for JBoss technology like JBoss Fuse.

For your other comment - then JBoss Developer Studio is totally free too. It is only if you download JBoss Developer Studio with a bundled runtime that you will be presented with the $0 subscription license. Thus this applies to the runtime not the IDE.

But since you are already using JBoss Fuse you are already using software that you (not me) call "nasty license fee stuff"

In case that still worries you then I suggest you install JBoss Tools from Eclipse Marketplace - exact same stuff, it just don't have the single install option thus requires more manual setup.

Comment: Thank-you for passing along this helpful information Max. :) I am confused on what you mean when you type, *"...this applies to the runtime not the IDE"*, in regards to a free version of JBoss Developer Studio. I will have to check out the `JBoss Tools` from the `Eclipse Marketplace`. :D

Comment: Okey, here is a second attempt:

Download JBoss Developer Studio = free, *no* $0 subscription license. As free as downloading Eclipse.

Download JBoss Developer Studio *bundled* with JBoss EAP = need to agree to $0 subscription license because the JBoss EAP runtime is bundled.

Hope that makes it clearer that JBoss Developer Studio is free, and it is only when you download runtimes like JBoss EAP or Fuse there are special constraints involved.